# Splitting a string from the points where alphabet system changes

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to create a list that has items only from 1 alphabet only, such as Latin alphabet or Hangul. One of the alphabet will always be Latin alphabet and other might change. I also don't want blank items in my list that is caused by the spaces between words.

I want to split it from the points where alphabet changes.

To give an example, my string is:

`"형 older brother 누나 older sister 언니 older sister 오빠 older brother"`
.

I want to create the list:

`["형", "older brother", "누나", "older sister", "언니", "older sister", "오빠", "older brother"]`

Can someone help?

Comment: will it always be english and one other alphabet or can there be a situation where you have 2 non english alphabets?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to specify that, thanks for mentioning. It will always be English and one other alphabet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex.

```
import re

s = "형 older brother 누나 older sister 언니 older sister 오빠 older brother"
#print(re.split(r"([^a-z\s]+)", s, re.IGNORECASE))
print([i for i in re.split(r"([^a-z\s]+)", s) if i])
```

Comment: Rakesh, it is printing a leading empty string as well..Can you correct that? `['', '형', ' older brother ', '누나', ' older sister ', '언니', ' older sister ', '오빠', ' older brother']`

Comment: I just edited the answer, to `print(re.split(r"([^a-z\s]+)", s, re.IGNORECASE))`. Otherwise capital letters are also used for splitting

Comment: You probably want `[i.strip() for i ...]` to remove the leading whitespace in each item as well.